# Different actions on different lines of a string in RUBY

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string:

```
aaaaaa; bbbbbbbb
cccccc; cccccccc
dddddd; dddddddd
```

I need to take different action in respect to different lines.
More precisely, I must do something-1 with the first line, something-2 with all the other, and something-3 with the last one. Pseudo code:

```
out.each_line { |ln|

   if ln first
       do somenthing-1
   end

   if ln others
       do somenthing-2
   end

   if ln last
       do somenthing-3
   end

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
lines = out.lines
do_something_1(lines.first)

lines[1..-2].each do |line|
  do_something_2(line)
end

do_something_3(lines.last)
```

This code will do some action on the first line, some other action on all lines except the first and the last, and a third action on the last line.

Comment: It seems that "lines[1..-2]" doen't work. It cuts a character of the second line and also takes the last line

Comment: If `lines` is an array of strings (the output of `out.lines`), `lines[1..-2]` is an array of the range of items from the original array from the second item to the one before last item - it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I find this alternative a bit more readable:

```rb
first, *middle, last = out.lines

do_something_1(first)
middle.each{|line| do_something_2(line) }
do_something_3(last)
```